# TypeError when trying to pass *args to re.findall

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have this method that extracts some html data and image links, organizes it into a pre-made template and then either shows me it via webbrowser.open or returns the whole html code as a string (when used for external programs)

Prior to this I was only calling this function internally and inputting url's manually, and the program successfully created the template every time. Now re.findall() doesn't accept the tuple *args, and no matter what I tried (`''.join, '{}'.format(tup), repr(), str()`), none of it worked. Using Python 2.7.12. So basically my question is how do I pass *args (which will always be a string) to create_template()?

```
def create_template(*args):
    p = re.compile('(?<=\/)[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?!.)')
    if args:        
        argstring = '{}'.format(args)
        itemID = re.findall(p,argstring)[0]
        new_html = change_links(itemID)
        info = get_walmart_info(itemID)
        template = finish_template(new_html,info)
        webbrowser.open('finished wtemplate.html')
        return template
    else:
        url = raw_input("Enter itemID/url: ")
        itemID = re.findall(p,url)[0]
        new_html = change_links(itemID)
        info = get_walmart_info(itemID)
        finish_template(new_html,info)
        webbrowser.open('finished wtemplate.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_template()
```

and the error I'm getting (when used externally, internal use still fine):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    wTemplate.create_template('37651390')
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gal\Programming\wTemplate.py", line 91, in create_template
    argstring = '{}'.format(*args)  
  File "C:\Python27amd64\lib\re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: What arguments are you passing in?

Comment: Your error and your code don't seem to match.

Comment: Can you provide an example input and the expected output? It's not clear to me what `create_template()` is supposed to do

Comment: I'm passing either a full url link or a specific part of it, as a string.

for example
`create_template('37651390')` will specifically go to [link](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Mainstays-Nightstand-End-Table-Multiple-Finishes/37651390), extract the item's description and images, and organize it in a predefined structure. The output is a very (very) long string full of html code that I need to pass to an 'AddItem' API that asks for html descriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating your code. In case you have zero or one inputs to your functions, there's no need to use a splat operator. Instead use a single input name, with a default argument to account for the case of no input:

```
def create_template(inpstr=None):
    p = re.compile('(?<=\/)[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?!.)')
    if inpstr:        # inpstr=='37651390' case
        argstring = '{}'.format(inpstr)
        itemID = re.findall(p,argstring)[0]
        # ...
    else:             # inpstr==None case
        url = raw_input("Enter itemID/url: ")
        itemID = re.findall(p,url)[0]
        # ...
```

Using `fun(*args)` is mostly necessary when there's a variable number of input arguments and you want to catch all in the input. For your case, you'd have needed

```
def create_template(*args):
    p = re.compile('(?<=\/)[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?!.)')
    if args:        # args==('37651390',)
        argstring = '{}'.format(args[0]) # <-- args[0]
    # ...
```

Instead, you were passing a length-1 tuple to `.format()`.

Comment: Okay, the part that I don't understand is what does `(inpstr=None)` do exactly.
Does it make inpstr None unless specified otherwise? Does it tell the interpreter to accept zero arguments ?

Comment: In any case, your answer was the one that solved it for me.
I understand *args is a list now... first time meddling with it.

Comment: @galalmighty It's a tuple, but they're close:) And yes, `inpstr=None` tells the interpreter that if there are no inputs (in that position), it will assign `None` to that variable. This makes this input parameter optional; just what you need.